# Blank delphi FMX app with entitlement for push notifications enabled crashes on start

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

Reproduction:

- File -> New -> Other -> Multi-Device Application.
- Tabbed with Navigation (or other non 3D, non blank app)
- Build and start the app as android 64-bit and launch is in the connected device.

This works.

Now, as soon as you go to:

- project options -> Application -> Entitlement List
- turn on "Receive push notifications"
- Then try to start the app.

The app will no longer be able to start.

The question here is, what exactly is the android API expecting to find in the APP, which causes this crash? I'm not getting into the debugger - the app closes before Delphi Rad studio 10.4.2 (using the v30 Android SDK) is even able to "hook" into anything. With as much as Rad studio is doing automatically, I'd expect it to create the required frame or app hook automatically, but there's just "nothing" that resembles useful information regarding this.

Main article on adding push notifications here:

- https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Firebase_Android_Support

And yes, I did follow that part as well, with the same crashing result. The google app emulator doesn't give me anything worthwhile either,. I'm a bit at a loss here.

Comment: Have you imported google play services json with Firebase credentials?

Comment: What you mean with last sentence? You done all the steps in Firebase support topic?

Comment: I did all the steps, imported the json, named the app / firebase app the same, added the stuff in formcreate same as described and the onX events. No dice.

Comment: The best way to determine what is going on is to use a logcat viewer, e.g [Device Lens](https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/DeviceLens) so you can see what error messages (if any are being generated). You could run Device Lens, in the filter section enter *firebase* in the Filter On Text edit, select only *Error* in the checkboxes, click the Start button, then start your app